# c# If statement always returns false

Tags: c#, linux, if-statement, mono

I'm currently developing a small server/client application for a personal project. The server is meant to be run in Linux under Mono while the client is being run from a Windows PC.

I have an issue where I am passing data to the server (In this case string value of "on" and "off") however an if statement is always returning a false value.

The code from the server is as follows

```
public void startServer() {
    TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(serverIP, 10000);
    listen.Start();

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("IP Address = {0}", serverIP.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Server is listening for connection");

    Socket a = listen.AcceptSocket();

    Console.WriteLine("Connection from {0}", a.RemoteEndPoint);

    ASCIIEncoding respond = new ASCIIEncoding();
    a.Send(respond.GetBytes("You are connected to LED Control Server"));

    bool keepListening = true;

    while (keepListening) {
        byte[] b = new byte[1000];
        a.Receive(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Message Received from {0}, string: {1}", a.RemoteEndPoint, recData(b));
        string serverMsg = procIns(recData(b));
        a.Send(respond.GetBytes(serverMsg));
    }
}

private string recData(byte[] b) //receiving data from the client {
    int count = b.Length;
    string message = "";
    for (int a = 0; a < count; a++) {
        message += Convert.ToChar(b[a]);
    }
    return message;
}

private string procIns(string instruction) {
    string returnMsg;

    Console.WriteLine(instruction.ToLower());

    if (instruction.ToLower() == "on") {
        FileGPIO gpio = new FileGPIO();
        gpio.OutputPin(FileGPIO.enumPIN.gpio17, true);
        returnMsg = "GPIO 17 1";
    } else if (instruction.ToLower() == "off") {
        FileGPIO gpio = new FileGPIO();
        gpio.OutputPin(FileGPIO.enumPIN.gpio17, false);
        returnMsg = "GPIO 17 0";
    } else {
        returnMsg = "Invalid Command";
    }

    return returnMsg;
}
```

The cause for the if statement in procIns method returning false is escaping me, if anyone could offer any advice I would appreciate it!

Comment: Did you check for any padding spaces?

Comment: Use a debugger, look at the actual value of `instruction`.  I assure you that the `if` statement is not broken.

Comment: FYI, `recData` is unnecessary. You can use something like `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);` instead.

Comment: `a.Receive(b);` doesn't ensure that you will get `b.Length` bytes. Check its return value.

Comment: `b.Length` should be about 1000.  Where are you keeping track of the number of bytes actually received?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your respond guys, I've just viewed the variable in the debugger and I am getting "on\0\0\0\0" (\0 is repeated many times) what could be causing the data to be sent like this? could it be that i have set byte[] = new byte[1000]?

Comment: HABO, I think you hit the nail on the head there. my byte array is too big for the data being received. I need to find out how to keep track of the bytes received

Comment: Keep in mind that TCP only guarantees that the bytes that go in at one end will come out in the same order at the other end.  It is a stream with no concept of "message".  You must be prepared to handle bytes dribbling in in arbitrary groups, e.g. the remote system may send "off" followed by "on".  You could receive "of" and "fon", or "offon".  Without a message length field or delimiter of some sort it may be difficult to interpret the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   while (keepListening) {
            byte[] b = new byte[1000];
            int bytesRcvd = a.Receive(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Message Received from {0}, string: {1}", a.RemoteEndPoint, recData(b));
            string serverMsg = procIns(recData(b, bytesRcvd ));
            a.Send(respond.GetBytes(serverMsg));
        }
```

`a.Receive(b)` method returns number of bytes received. You can store the value in some variable and pass the variable to `recData` method.

```
    private string recData(byte[] b, int bytesRcvd) {
    string message = "";
    for (int a = 0; a < bytesRcvd; a++) {
        message += Convert.ToChar(b[a]);
    }
    return message;
}
```

The number of bytes received will help in truncating the extra values in byte array.

Comment: You should really not use `Convert.ToChar` in a loop here.  Choose a string encoding, then use one of the `System.Text.Encoding` subclasses.

Also check for leading/trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it would have to be padded spaces.  Try this instead...

```
if (instruction.Trim().ToLower() == "on")
```

Comment: Still get the same, I have checked the variable value and it has the string "on" but then it's followed by loads of /o/o/o/o/o/o/o what could be causing that?

Comment: In the example from your question, you don't check the size of the returned data.  You allocate a 1000-byte array, but `a.Receive(b)` only actually fills the first 0 <= N <= 1000 bytes of this array.

Then you turn the entire buffer into a string.

In .NET, strings have a length, they're not zero-terminated.  A zero byte is actually a valid characters.  You're getting 1000-N of these at the end of your string.